# Shorten 'if' statement with high number of 'or' conditions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement

Suppose that we have this `if` statement in MATLAB:

```
if rn == 1 || rn == 2 || rn == 3 || rn == 4 || rn == 5
  %% Some calculations
elseif rn == 6 || rn == 7 || rn == 8 || rn == 9 || rn == 10
  %% Some calculations
end
```

Any way to shorten this `if` statement?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by using [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) to check a vector of values:

```
if any(rn == 1:5)
  %% Some calculations
else if any(rn == 6:10)
  %% Some calculations
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For performance, using `||` (allowing short-circuiting) is preferable to the following, but if you really want to avoid writing out extra `OR` clauses, you could make use of [ismember](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)

```
if ismember(rn, 1:5)
  %% Some calculations
elseif ismember(rn, 6:10)
  %% Some calculations
end
```

which returns `true` if `rn` is a member of the array (`1:5` and `5:10`, respectively), and `false`, otherwise.

Another alternative is using [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) as follows

```
if find(1:5 == rn)
  %% Some calculations
elseif find(6:10 == rn)
  %% Some calculations
end
```

Since you check for equality in an vector of distinct values, `find` will either return a single index `>= 1` which will evaluate as `true`,  or an empty matrix, which will evaluate as `false`.

---

If you know `rn` to be an integer, you can naturally just check if its in the range representation of the above

```
if rn >= 1 && rn <= 5
  %% Some calculations
elseif rn >= 6 && rn <= 10
  %% Some calculations
end
```